# Combine IdentityDbContext and TrackerContext

Tags: c#, entity-framework, owin, asp.net-identity-2, tracker-enabled-dbcontext

I have an existing EF-Project which uses "[Tracker Enabled DbContext](https://github.com/bilal-fazlani/tracker-enabled-dbcontext)". To work with this package I have to derive from its "TrackerContext":

```
public class MyContext : TrackerContext {}
```

TrackContext itself derives from DBContext:

```
public class TrackerContext : DbContext, ITrackerContext, IDbContext, IDisposable
```

(info from metadata)

Now I want to add Identity to my project (OWIN). For this to happen I have to derive from IdentityDBContext:

```
 public class MyContext: IdentityDbContext<UserOwin>
```

So I am in a bit of a dilemma here:
How can I use AspNetIdentity without losing the Tracking functionality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved this. There is a nuget-package for exactly that specific issue:

```
TrackerEnabledDbContext.Identity
```

Comment: Shall i use this `TrackerEnabledDbContext.Identity` for auditing asp.net identity tables?